# SQL server using unpivot function

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

How would you obtain the following output using SQL?

```
 Type:  Value  Type2       Value2
    p_01    1     ofpk_01     1
    p_02    2     ofpk_02     2
    p_03    3     ofpk_03     3
```

Table structure

```
 create table test(p_01     int,
                   p_02     int,
                   p_03     int,
                   ofpk_01  int,
                   ofpk_02  int,
                   ofpk_03  int)
```

[SQL fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6fbc7/1)

Is this possible with unpivot function?  here is what I've got so far:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution is to use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT  ca.*
FROM    dbo.Test x
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT 'p_01' AS Type1, x.p_01 AS Value1, 'ofpk_01' AS Type2, x.ofpk_01 AS Value2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'p_02' AS Type1, x.p_02 AS Value1, 'ofpk_02' AS Type2, x.ofpk_02 AS Value2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'p_03' AS Type1, x.p_03 AS Value1, 'ofpk_03' AS Type2, x.ofpk_03 AS Value2
) ca;
```

**<kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6fbc7/10)</kbd>**

Or if 2008+ this can be shortened to

```
SELECT  ca.*
FROM    dbo.Test x
CROSS APPLY
(VALUES

    ('p_01', x.p_01, 'ofpk_01', x.ofpk_01),
    ('p_02', x.p_02, 'ofpk_02', x.ofpk_02),
    ('p_03', x.p_03, 'ofpk_03', x.ofpk_03)
) ca(Type1, Value1, Type2, Value2);
```

**<kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6fbc7/9)</kbd>**

Comment: +1 for table definition given in the question with no useful indexes means one scan rather than three scans with the `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with `unpivot`. I think you'll have to do something like:

```
Select
    'p_01' type,
    p_01 value,
    'ofpk_01' type2,
    ofpk_01 value2
From
    test
Union All
Select
    'p_02',
    p_02,
    'ofpk_02',
    ofpk_02
From
    test
Union All
Select
    'p_03',
    p_03,
    'ofpk_03',
    ofpk_03
From
    test
```

**<kbd>[Example Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6fbc7/4)</kbd>**

Comment: I thought so, thanks for trying :)